# How to force a dependency conflict for benchmarks?

Tags: package-management, gentoo, benchmark

I want to measure the time portage needs for solving dependency conflicts on a gentoo system. For a benchmark I need a reproducible conflict situation. It should have many solvable conflicts.

`/usr/portage/*-*` will be copied once to `/usr/local/portage-benchmark`

**How can I force portage to use only this copy and trigger a conflict?**

Answer (score 0):

You can put `/usr/local/portage-benchmark` at `/etc/portage/repos.conf`

See this [Gentoo Wiki Link](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki//etc/portage/repos.conf) for more information.

Something like:

```
[DEFAULT]
main-repo = gentoo

[gentoo]
location = /usr/local/portage-benchmark
auto-sync = no
```